# VBScript Error Message and Handling

Tags: excel, vbscript, smtp

So I have this *Auto Email Script*, it all works fine but the problem I am having is that when an email pops up that isn't valid it will error out and quit, what I am wondering is, is there a way to tell it if there is an error skip that record and move onto the next one?

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("##############").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xls" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)

set sh = wb.Sheets("Auto Email Script")
row = 4
email = sh.Range("A" & row)
LastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim f                                   
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("#####################.txt", ForReading)                                       
BodyText = f.ReadAll

For r = row to LastRow
    If App.WorkSheetFunction.CountA(sh.Rows(r)) <> 0 Then 
    email = sh.Range("A" & row)
    sh.Range("I" & row).Value = "Sent"
        row = row + 1
    End if

    If email = "" Then
    Wscript.Quit
    End if

objMessage.Subject = "Billing: Meter Read" 
objMessage.From = "################"
objMessage.To = email
objMessage.TextBody = BodyText

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "################"
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
objMessage.Send

Next
wb.Save
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
wb.Close
End If
Next
```

Comment: on error resume next?

Comment: which line fails? objMessage.Send?

Comment: It all works fine until it gets to a blank row or a row with an invalid email address, I just want it to skip that row and move on instead of throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not clear to me what you mean by "invalid address". If you mean a malformed address you could validate it e.g. with a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9._]*@[a-z][a-z0-9-]*\.[a-z]+$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

If re.Test(email) Then
  'send mail
End If
```

Note that the expression above is rather conservative and covers only a safe subset of all potentially valid addresses.

If you mean that an address is rejected by your mail server you need to enable error handling for `objMessage.Send` as @mehow suggested:

```
On Error Resume Next
objMessage.Send
If Err Then WScript.Echo Hex(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: The second option you gave is exactly what I am looking for, where exactly would I put this in the script? Thanks alot!

Comment: Replace the line `objMessage.Send` with the snippet I posted.